# stacked waterfall charts in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, waterfall, stacked

We have a requirement for stacked waterfall charts (we are using highcharts.com). 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/8JP8T/ gives an option for creating waterfall charts but we need to create stacks. Anyone has done this before?
Thanks !!

Comment: Could you provide an example image for what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can make stacked bars "levitate" by making an ghost series, then setting the ghost series to have an opacity of 0.

```
$.each(chart.series[2].data, function(i, point) {
  if (i==2) {
    point.graphic.attr({opacity: 0, 'stroke-width': 0});
  }
}
```

This fiddle illustrates the basic idea.  Note that you need to turn shadows off and set showInLegend to false too to get the full ghostly effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/6UPrg/13/

Answer (score 1):

Based in your example, you may be interested in the [`stacking` property](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-bar--stacking) found within highcharts.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    //other properties...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I had to modify the js code (highcarts.js)

    `pointStack.cum = yBottom = pointStack.cum - yValue;``

to 

    `pointStack.cum = pointStack.cum - yValue;`

Basically, the stacks ignore the `low` value in options.
Another other ways of doing this ?

Comment: short of editing highcharts as you have, I don't think it is possible to do what you have done. You should add your answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

http://highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Comment: thats the normal column chart. I got it working. Look at https://github.com/toamitkumar/Stacked-Waterfall/tree/master/stacked-waterfall